# (#32) Page request limited reached Facebook API response

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook API to pull data about various public pages that I have in my DB.
It is working fine, but after some time I keep getting this error from API.
After this error I am unable pull any data for any pages. Is this error related to just a page data or this may occur any time?

Pleas provide some explanation if any one knows. So that I can optimize my code to handle this situation.

Thanks..